# Why does $x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4x^2$ have a restricted domain to the solution while $x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+x^3\sin x$ does not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation:

$x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+x^3\sin x$ , where $y(\pi)=0$

The solution to this differential equation is $y=-x^2\cos x+x\sin x-x\pi$. When I graph it, it appears to be continuous everywhere.

However, shouldn't the differential equation not exist at $x=0$, because $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+x^3\sin x}{x}$?

But when graphing the solution curve, the curve does not have an asymptote at $x=0$, which would be the case if the derivative did not exist.

Onto the second differential equation:

$x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4x^2$, where $y(1)=2$

The solution is $y=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$, $x>0$.

If I divide both sides of the differential equation by x, I would have: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x^2-2y}{x}$, and the derivative does not exist at $x=0$.

Why does the second differential equation have a solution with a domain while the first does not, even though both derivatives are undefined at $x=0$?

My guess is that for the first differential equation, $x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+x^3\sin x$, when I plug the solution into the differential equation, I get:

$x\frac{dy}{dx} =-x^2\cos x+x\sin x-x\pi + x^3\sin x$

Dividing x on both sides, I get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} =-x\cos x+\sin x-\pi + x^2\sin x$

Notice how in this differential equation, the differential equation is defined when $x=0$, which might be the reason why the solution, $y=-x^2\cos x+x\sin x-x\pi$, does not have a restricted domain?

However, with the second differential equation, $x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4x^2$, whe I plug in the solution into the differential equation, I get:

$x\frac{dy}{dx}+2(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})=4x^2$

Simplifying:

$x\frac{dy}{dx}=2x^2-\frac{2}{x^2}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-\frac{2}{x^3}$

Notice how in this differential equation, the differential equation is not defined when $x=0$, which might be the reason why the solution, $y=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ has a domain of $x>0$?

**My reasoning as to why I plugged the solution into the differential equation (now that I thought of it, I could have just taken the derivative of the solution, but it achieves the same thing):**

By taking the derivative of the solution, I can see if the derivative exists at $x=0$, allowing me to know if there should be a domain. (Although I am not sure if this works since again, going back to my original question, why was the differential equation undefined in $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+x^3\sin x}{x}$ at $x=0$ but the solution curve not having a restricted domain.)

Is my guess just a coincidence? What should I do to know whether the solution has a domain or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, look again at the solution for $y$. It has the factor $x$ in all its terms, so when you plug that into $y'=(y+x^3\sin(x))/x$ the denominator gets canceled out and you have a smooth derivative. We call this situation a **removable singularity.**

Even though the function has a removable singularity, the differential equation still shows a singular behavior. You can't specify an arbitrary boundary condition at the singular point $x=0$: if you try a nonzero function value there the differential equation contradicts it, and if you try $y(0)=0$ you get a nonunique solution. So while a specific solution has its singularity removed, the set of overall solutions still behaves singularly by all of them being forced through $(0,0)$.